# How to force Rows to fill horizontal space in a Positioned Column inside a Stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here's my widget tree:

```
Stack(
  children:[
    IrrelevantWidget(),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(...),
            Row(...),
            Row(...),
            ...
```

It works fine, but I'd like all the `Row()` to have the same `width` as the `widest Row()`.
The `Container()` containing the `Column()` has the width of the widest `Row()`, but I can't find a way to stretch the other `Row()` to the full width of the `Container()`.

Everything I tried either breaks the view with a `paint error` or enlarges the `Container()` to the full width of the screen due to the nature of `Stack()`.

Is it possible?

Comment: how about ? ,if you want to make container fullwidth, you can add property `left:0` to the positioned, and for the container `aligment:Alignment.centerRight` to keep align right. ?

Comment: I don't want the container to be fullwidth. I want the rows to fill the container's width. If I set left: 0 everything takes the full screen width. But that's not what I want. I need a small box on the top right corner taking up the minimum space required but with all children (rows) with the same size.

Comment: wrap your widget with `Flexible`

Comment: @mohammadesmaili Flexible doesn't work in Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping that Column in `IntrinsicWidth` should expand each Row to the largest of all the children of the Column.

Answer (score 1):

Check `boxy: ^2.0.6+2` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy), it provides utilities for flex, custom multi-child layouts, dynamic widget inflation, slivers, and more

Comment: Boxy wouldn't help here unfortunately, `BoxyColumn` can only base its cross-axis size on a single child, for multiple children you should use a regular `Column` and `IntrinsicWidth`.